# Does Kubernetes-1.1.2 supports ubuntu or debian VM on 'Microsoft Azure'?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have tried `Ubuntu-14.04, 15.10` and `Debian-Jessie` images. But clusters not working.

Comment: What exactly did you try? What is "not working"? Any error messages? Be more detailed, please.

Comment: I have used the ubuntu/debian image instead of coreos image and created a cluster. But on each node no packages was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try or inspire from with this template (based on CentOS) that allows to deploy Kubernetes cluster on Azure: https://github.com/dxfrance/azurekubernetes

Comment: Based on CentOS the cluster works perfectly, But I also need for Ubuntu and Debian.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to modify the template to use Ubuntu or debian ? It should work on Ubuntu 14-04 (cf. http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/)

Comment: Here "KUBERNETES_PROVIDER" is ubuntu. I need Azure